# Adding textfield to table cell

Tags: iphone

I am trying to add a textfield to a table cell. Can anyone please correct this code

```
aCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"UserIDCell"] autorelease];
                    aCell.textLabel.text = @"User Name";
                    aCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                    UITextField *user_ID_TextField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                    aCell.accessoryView = user_ID_TextField1;
                    [user_ID_TextField1 release];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this example.

```
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
    textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
    textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    textField.delegate = self;  
    [aCell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```

Remember to add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your header file.